# Update _id of a document in PouchDb

Tags: pouchdb

Is there a way of updating the id of the document? I have tried to achieve that with the following code but this throws an error(below):

```
this.db.get('oldId')
  .then(document => {
    this.logsheetDB.put({
      _id: 'newId',
      _rev: document._rev,
      objectToInsert,
    });
  })
```

Error:

```
{"status":409,"name":"conflict","message":"Document update conflict"}"
```

Is there any other way than recreating it (document)?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change a document `_id`, it would not make sense.

If you get a document and changes its `id`, you would create a clone with a different `id`. If you want to do this, you just have to remove the `_rev`.

Why do you need to remove the `_rev` when changing the `_id`? We normally pass the `_rev` property to avoid conflicts and inform CouchDB that the document we are updating is based on the revision X. By changing `_id`,  we are creating a new document so there is no existing document to revise.

Comment: NB: Don't forget about deleting the old doc after you cloned it